# why isnt this jquery working properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this site's navigation: [link removed]

I am attempting to use Jonathan Snook's jQuery background image animation http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

The code used:

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="about-us"><a href="#">about us</a></li>                                                              
                <li class="services"><a href="#">services</a></li>
                <li class="products"><a href="#">products</a></li>
                <li class="news"><a href="#">news</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/navigation-->
```

CSS:

```
div.navigation {
    display: block;
    height: 47px;
}

ul.navigation li { 
    float: left; 
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(../i/menu-sprite.jpg) no-repeat;
}

ul.navigation li a { display: block; height: 47px;}

ul.navigation li.about-us { width: 197px; background-position: 0 0; }
ul.navigation li.about-us:hover { width: 197px; background-position: 0 -47px; }

ul.navigation li.services { width: 200px; background-position: -197px 0; }
ul.navigation li.services:hover { width: 200px; background-position: -197px -47px; }

ul.navigation li.products { width: 210px; background-position: -396px 0; }
ul.navigation li.products:hover { width: 210px; background-position: -396px -47px; }

ul.navigation li.news { width: 152px; background-position: -606px 0; }
ul.navigation li.news:hover { width: 152px; background-position: -606px -47px; }

ul.navigation li.contact { width: 183px; background-position: -758px 0; }
ul.navigation li.contact:hover { width: 183px; background-position: -758px -47px; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$('ul.navigation li a')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 -47px)"}, 
            {duration:500})
        })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
            {duration:500})
        })
});
```

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't *seriously* expect us to say why 'this jquery' isn't working *without* showing us what you've done?

Comment: sorry - not having a good day :)

Comment: It uses a jQuery plugin. Did you include it?

Comment: Yes. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="j/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="j/jquery.backgroundPosition.js"></script>

Comment: Note: I edited the answer and took out the code because that is not what you probably want. It replaces all your links to "About us". You'd probably need to apply different x positions for different links and not do it all in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a background-image applied to your `ul.navigation li a`. Yet, you are attempting to set and animate the background-position style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is not working but I am assuming your `jquery` is not animating the `background position` it is because you have already given a `hover` state in your css which overrides the animation and instantly moves your background position...
Another thing in your javascript try using since you have `background position` for `.about-us` and not `.about-us a`

```
$('ul.navigation li.about-us').stop().animate(
                {backgroundPosition:"(0 -47px)"}, 
                {duration:500})
```

but in your jquery code you are again reseting the background position on hover too `'0 0'`... so I would advice you to remove the `css:hover` state

Answer (score 1):

You must replace selector:

```
$(this).stop().animate(
```

with:

```
$(this).parent('li').animate(
```

because with stop() you select a tag, and you need to select li tag.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is often overlooked with background animations in jquery is they need an additional plugin (it's a small one though), to make it work.
The plugin can be found at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect.